# Multiple Ajax Form Data Upload Jquery

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, jsp, file-upload

I am trying to upload multiple files to a folder and this isint working as I am getting an error in the logs: "Required MultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present". Please see my below code and direct me where I am going wrong.

```
<input type="file" id = 'attachmentFileUploadInput' multiple style="display: none;" >

    function makeProgress(number){   
      var url = getRelativeURL("web/fileUpload");        
      var formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('number', number);
      fls = document.getElementById("attachmentFileUploadInput").files; //length of files... 
      for(j=0;j<fls.length;j++){
          formData.append('files[]', fls[j]);  //note files[] not files
      }
      // this wroked for single file upload -formData.append('file', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]); 
      console.log("form data " + formData);
      $.ajax({
          url : url,
          data : formData,
          processData : false,
          contentType : false,
          type : 'POST',
          success : function(data) {
           FileUploadVisible(true);
           $('#attachmentModal').modal('hide')
           $(':input','#attachmentModal').val("");
            $("#pbarmain").hide();
            $("#pbar").hide();
            $("#actionPlanDiv").hide();
            setObjectEnabled('#Upload',false);
          },
          error : function(err) {
              FileUploadErrorVisible(true);
          }
     });

        }
```

Server side:

```
private static String UPLOADED_FOLDER = "C://temp//";

@RequestMapping(value = { "/fileUpload" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String uploadFile( @RequestParam("number") String number, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, MultipartHttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
{       
    try {
        File directory = new File(UPLOADED_FOLDER + number);
                if (! directory.exists()){
                    directory.mkdir();
                  }
            byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
            Path path = Paths.get(UPLOADED_FOLDER + number + "//" + file.getOriginalFilename());
            Files.write(path, bytes);
            logger.info("You have successfully uploaded '" + file.getOriginalFilename() + "'");
            return("File Uploaded");


    } catch (Exception e) {
        res.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        logger.error("Failed to upload file '" + file.getOriginalFilename() + "'", e);
        return("File Not Uploaded");
    }
}

}
```

Comment: You append file name with `files[]` but in server side expect with name `file` e.g: `@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file`

Comment: How do i update the server side to expect files[], what do i do need to update on my code?

Comment: did you found your solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`contentType: 'multipart/form-data'` this is what you are missing

Comment: error:

Caused by: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found